# How can I scan for BLE devices on Iphone 6 which do not advertise a name

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

We are using Swift and IOS CBCentralManager.  We have a Bluetooth Low energy (Dual mode device)

The Dual mode device advertising packet does not have a name or shortened name due to a lack of space.

When we call "scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)" with the service UUID which is included in the Advertising frame we only get a response if we also have a short device name included.

So with a name field, we can detect the device.  Without the name field we can not detect the device.  We are expecting a CBPeripheral to be returned, obviously with a NIL name.

We get a response on early Iphones, such as Iphone 5, but later Iphones and Ipads do not get a response.

3rd party software such as Lightblue can detect these devices.   This 3rd party software detects correctly every time on every device we have tested.

There must be something we are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a poorly documented option by Apple.  It seems that this is the option to cover this use case.

```
let CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: String
```

Apple must see a duplicate ID (or null) if there is no name in the Advertisment.

Here is apples write up [Apple Scan feature AllowDuplicatesKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerscanoptionallowduplicateskey)

This must pop up quite often because of the size limits of the Advertising frames in BLE.

I can see why many devs would choose not to waste space in the 32 byte advertising frame on a name for the GUI when the device is not consumer targeted.